# using left join and concat within three tables and return zero if no record found

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still new here ,and i'm trying to return 0(zero) values if no record found in my table but the current query i use is not working ,
so there are 3 tables that i already simplified in my database which is :
 1. theater :

```
+------------+--------------+
| theater_id | theater_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | THEATER 1    |
|          2 | THEATER 2    |
+------------+--------------+
```

2. showtime :

```
+-------------+-----------+
| showtime_id | showtimes |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 | 10:00 AM  |
|           2 | 2:00 PM   |
+-------------+-----------+
```

3. transaction :

```
+----------------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| transaction_id | seat_no | showtime_id | theater_id |    date    |
+----------------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|              1 | 1A      |           1 |          1 | 2017-04-04 |
|              2 | 2A      |           2 |          2 | 2017-04-04 |
|              3 | 3A      |           1 |          1 | 2017-04-04 |
|              4 | 2A      |           1 |          1 | 2017-04-04 |
+----------------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

query that i'm currently working on it :

```
SELECT   CONCAT(theater.theater_name,' ',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT showtime.showtimes SEPARATOR ' ')) as 2into1,
         COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0)
FROM     transaction
         LEFT JOIN theater ON theater.theater_id = transaction.theater_id
         LEFT JOIN showtime ON showtime.showtime_id = transaction.showtime_id
WHERE    transaction.date = "2017-04-04"
GROUP BY theater.theater_id,
         showtime.showtime_id
ORDER BY theater.theater_name
```

and the result of the query is :

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+
|      2into1        | coalesce(count(*), 0) |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
| THEATER 1 10:00 AM |                     3 |
| THEATER 2 2:00 PM  |                     1 |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

what i really wanted that it will give a full of theater and showtime detail and return zero if there's no record found on transaction, the reason i'm using concat is i'm going to make some chart that 2 into 1 field will be X-Axis and count(*) will be Y-AXIS

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+
|      2into1        | coalesce(count(*), 0) |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
| THEATER 1 10:00 AM |                     3 |
| THEATER 1 2:00 PM  |                     0 |
| THEATER 2 10:00 AM |                     0 |
| THEATER 2 2:00 PM  |                     1 |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

alright, i hope you guys understand and can help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `cross join` between theaters and showtimes, then a left join:

```
SELECT CONCAT(th.theater_name, ' ', sh.showtimes) as 2into1,
       COUNT(t.theater_id)
FROM theater th CROSS JOIN
     showtime st LEFT JOIN
     transaction t
     ON th.theater_id = t.theater_id AND
        st.showtime_id = t.showtime_id AND
        t.date = '2017-04-04'
GROUP BY th.theater_id, st.showtime_id
ORDER BY th.theater_name;
```

Notes:

- `showtime_id` is in the `GROUP BY`.  There is no need to `GROUP_CONCAT` on a related field.  There should be only one value.
- dates and strings should use single quotes to delimit the values
- `COUNT()` returns `0` if there are no matching rows.  `COALESCE()` is superfluous.
- The condition on the date needs to go into the `ON` clause because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: already did with ur query suggestion but it gives the value 1 instead of 0 for every 2into1 fields that has no record on transaction table

Comment: it's solved now, i was changing COUNT(*)  to COUNT(t.fieldname),
thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @wumBo_ . . . Yes, of course.  You want `0` when there is no match.